# How to round numeric output from yaml.dump, in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, rounding, precision

Is there a clean way to control number rounding output of `yaml.dump`? For example, I have a class with different complexity variables, some of which are double precision numbers I want to be round to say 4th digit. This `yaml` output is for display only; it will not be loaded (i.e. `yaml.load` will not be used).

As a naive example, consider class `A` below:

```
import yaml
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1/7
        self.b = 'some text'
        self.c = [1/11, 1/13, 1/17, 'some more text']

    def __repr__(self):
        return yaml.dump(self)

A()
```

with output

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
a: 0.14285714285714285
b: some text
c: [0.09090909090909091, 0.07692307692307693, 0.058823529411764705, some more text]
```

and desired output:

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
a: 0.1429
b: some text
c: [0.0909, 0.0769, 0.0588, some more text]
```

I suppose this can be done with `yaml.representative` in some clean way.
I'd like to avoid using rounding of string *output*, because the actual class structure can be more complex (recursive, etc.)

Comment: I’m not sure why you can’t just use `round(number, precision)`?

Comment: The class structure is dynamic and complex (number of variables can change). It can contain variables which are themselves classes of other variables. I think a clean way to do so is to define a representative, which identifies double-precision numbers (`float`, `array.float`) and rounds them before concatenating to `dump` output. Does this make sense?

Comment: To be honest I’m not sure I understand your code. You probably need to post more details than this. However, the basic concepts should be that you find a way in your classes to define the precision that you want and send it, along with the number, to the function `round(number, precision)`. It’s either that, or you need to define another condition that sets the `precision` parameter, but since I don’t filly understand what you’re trying to do, I can’t tell you how to define that condition.

Comment: Let me know what appears confusing. I'll gladly clarify. My code should run in your Python console, producing first output, but I need the second output. Still, I do not want use `round(a,4)`, `round(b,4)`,..., because variables can change. Another instance of this class have variables `x`, `y`. I think the rounding can be incorporated into the `dump` itself via `representative` method. Is this clearer?

Comment: @Y2H The code is using the [pyyaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) package to serialize a python class.

Comment: @memoselyk: thank you. I wasn't sure what else to add to the question to make it clearer. So, far it seems clear to me, but I will gladly add clarity, if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could round it manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import yaml

def float_representer(dumper, value):
    text = '{0:.4f}'.format(value)
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float', text)
yaml.add_representer(float, float_representer)

print(yaml.safe_dump([1 / 11, 1 / 13, 1 / 17, 'some more text']))
print(yaml.dump([1 / 11, 1 / 13, 1 / 17, 'some more text']))
```

#### Output

```
[0.09090909090909091, 0.07692307692307693, 0.058823529411764705, some more text]

[0.0909, 0.0769, 0.0588, some more text]
```

You might need to add more code for corner-cases, see [`represent_float()`](http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/tags/3.10/lib/yaml/representer.py#L187-L205) as [@memoselyk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944670/4279).

Comment: Works beautifully. I was just trying to put this together (thanks to @memoselyk), but your input was of great value.

Comment: @EmilyHill: you could also use `text = '%.4f' % value` (to fix the format). I haven't used it because I thought ([it seems incorrectly](https://bugs.python.org/msg182693)) that it uses a different [rounding mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) but I can't find a counter-example at the moment.

Comment: all great suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: @EmilyHill: I've investigated it further and found that I was right: `round()` and `'%f'` may produce different results e.g.,  `f = 0.00635; print("{0:.4f} {1}".format(f, round(f, 4)))` prints `0.0063 0.0064` on Python 2.6 on my machine. There should be no difference on Python 3. I've updated the answer to use string formatting, to get uniform results on various python versions.

Comment: Interesting to know. Thanks for investigation and help.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own *repesenter* for floats that formats the float numbers as you desire, and replace the existing representer with `yaml.add_representer(float, my_custom_repesenter)`.

[Here](http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/trunk/lib/yaml/representer.py#L187) you can find the default representer for floats. You can take that code as an starting point and only change the path where value is not `[+-].inf` or `.nan`, and massage the `value` into your desired precision.